# How to pass date variable in open query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to pass date variable in open query but it shows error like

> "Incorrect syntax near + "

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @fromdt DATETIME = '2018-04-07';
 DECLARE @EndDate1 DATETIME = '2018-04-07';
    Select * from openquery(TIMEV,
       'SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(badgenumber,"0"," "))," ","0") badgenumber,
checktime as dt
from checkinout a 
join USERINFO c on c.userid=a.userid  
        WHERE checktime >= '''''+CONVERT(CHAR(10), @fromdt, 120)+'''''  AND ''''' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), @EndDate1, 120) + ''''' ')
```

I am stuck here .Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you tried manipulating the date parameters in a separate command? You should be able to pass the parameters in rather than using dynamic sql

Comment: To clarify a bit, set @param = convert(@param...)

Comment: @LJ01 - this wouldn't help because the `OPENQUERY` documentation explicitly forbids using any variables. So it's not a problem of converting, it's a problem of any variable being passed to it. Should be remedied, though, with something like in my answer. The provided link has multiple workarounds for this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not seeing any point in using openquery at all. Is there something in there that can't be done using a standard query?

Answer (score 2):

`OPENQUERY` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql) explicitly says:

> OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments.

Therefore, using a trick from [this site](https://support.microsoft.com/hr-hr/help/314520/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-linked-server-query) you should be able to do it like this:

```
DECLARE @fromdt DATETIME = '2018-04-07';
DECLARE @EndDate1 DATETIME = '2018-04-07';

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 
'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(TIMEV,
    '' SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(badgenumber,"0"," "))," ","0") badgenumber,
       checktime AS dt
       FROM checkinout a 
         JOIN USERINFO c on c.userid=a.userid  
       WHERE checktime >= ''''' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), @fromdt, 120) + '''''  AND ''''' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), @EndDate1, 120) + ''''' ''
)';

EXEC(@query);
```

**EDIT:** there are also two other methods suggested in the link I provided above the code snippet if you wish to try them out.

Comment: I successfully adapted this approach (but using 121 as [the `CONVERT` style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles)).