# Passing Variable Into OpenQUERY SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, loops, variables, openquery

*EDIT: SQL Server Version*
I'm trying to pass this variable into my open query using this guide from Microsoft: [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314520/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-linked-server-query)

I'm running into this error message "Statement(s) could not be prepared." Which I believe means something is wrong with the OpenQuery. I'm just not sure what is wrong.
Here's the code:

```
DECLARE @ticketid INT, @QLFD VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @ticketid = '296272348'
SELECT @QLFD = 'SELECT
                    *
                FROM 
                    OPENQUERY(
                    [Server_name],''
                        SELECT
                            ticket_id
                            , QLFD_SPD_AMT
                        FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
                        WHERE ticket_id = @ticketid
                    '')'
EXEC (@QLFD)
```

Could you help me identify the error? I prefer to do it passing the whole query as one.
Thanks!
Edit:
After looking at suggestions made by @Larnu. I have adjusted my code to:

```
DECLARE @ticketid INT--, @QLFD NVARCHAR(Max)
SELECT @ticketid = '296272348'
DECLARE @QLFD NVARCHAR(Max) = 'SELECT
                    *
                FROM 
                    OPENQUERY(
                    [Server_name],''
                        SELECT
                            ticket_id
                            , QLFD_SPD_AMT
                        FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
                        WHERE ticket_id = QUOTENAME(@ticketid, '''''''')
                    '')';
EXEC (@QLFD);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass date variable in open query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714919/how-to-pass-date-variable-in-open-query)

Comment: You can't parametrise a query in `OPENQUERY`; you would need to *safely* inject the value.

Comment: @Larnu, could you show me some documentation that will show me how to safely inject the variable?

Comment: There isn't really "documentation" on it. Just ensure you use `QUOTENAME` appropriately, or (for longer strings) ensure you use `REPLACE` to quote the value properly.

Comment: @Larnu, So I adjusted the bottom line of the query to `WHERE ticket_id = QUOTENAME(@ticketid, '''''''')` Adding triple quote in the query since the openquery starts with a double. Still getting an error. Thanks anyways!

Comment: That suggests you're doing something wrong, then @GaganBal . Also, if you're getting an error, share it...

Comment: @Larnu, sorry I just added it again.

Comment: `@ticketid` is still in the remote query, @GaganBal , you didn't inject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, you can't parametrise a query with `OPENQUERY` you have **safely** inject the values.

Normally that would be with `QUOTENAME` or `REPLACE`, but you don't actually need to do that here, due to the value being a numerical data type, so you can just concatenate it in:

```
DECLARE @ticketid int = 296272348; --Don't wrap numerical datatypes with quotes.

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @OpenQuery nvarchar(4000);

SET @OpenQuery = CONCAT(N'SELECT QLFD_SPD_AMT
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
WHERE ticket_id = ',@ticketid,N';'); --As it's an int we dont need to quote

SET @SQL = CONCAT(N'SELECT @ticketid AS ticket_id, QLFD_SPD_AMT
FROM OPENQUERY([servername],N''',REPLACE(@OpenQuery,'''',''''''),N''');';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ticketid int', @ticketid;
```